# Вопрос по выводу var_dump

Tags: php

Я правильно понимаю, что подобный вывод

```
object(WP_Post)[4278] {
...
```

означает, что конкретный объект `WP_Post` - это 4278й по счету созданный объект в текущем рантайме? В документации через ctrl + f не нашел ничего подходящего. [Вот](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/ec974c439724e8b4151412eaa0caba5aec5e1c49/ext/standard/var.c#L138) конкретное место в сорцах, но я уже ни черта не понимаю.

Comment: @eicto, мда, это xdebug видимо, а я в чистый пых полез.

> количество вообще объектов в рантайме, но это ничего особо не значит для программиста

Вот, мне нужно знать, насколько этой цифре можно доверять. Ну то есть в конкретной ситуации это ни на что не влияет, тормозит оно в любом случае, просто интересно.

Comment: ну там в примере видно, что она то уменьшается то увеличивается, особенно интересно, когда я объект задестроил, циферка не сбросилась, и неясно утекло оно или просто номер ссылки вверх ушел, может надо для надежности проверки переполнение по этой циферке устроить ?

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/21e01f2b70d133acffd82e505f70b65a996b0fd0/Zend/zend_hash.h#L227

и надо еще как объявляется Z_OBJDEBUG_PP найти, тогда будет понятно где оно что берет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

там точно квадратные скобки ? (в исходнике решетка или круглые скобки)

в круглых получается просто кол-во свойств а после # - количество вообще объектов в рантайме (может на момент создания), но это  ничего особо не значит для программиста ибо:

http://ideone.com/LWD6Fz

видимо зависит как-то от мусорщика или дефрагментатора этих номеров, угадать что там именно будет, не шибко просто.

здесь есть ссылки на доки и еще одно мнение, https://stackoverflow.com/a/8788162/815386

модеры - не делайте это ответом, я не знаю на самом деле :)

Answer (score 0):

попробуй сконвертировать в массив и вывести длину echo count(array()$yourVariable) думаю получится тоже самое число

Comment: @Kandrat, у меня нет доступа к, гхм, "всем переменным в рантайме в виде массива"